# ioredis - ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm dealing with a `ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache.` issue from ioredis and Elasticache. This is my clustering config

```
const clusterOptions = {
    enableReadyCheck: true,
    retryDelayOnClusterDown: 300,
    retryDelayOnFailover: 1000,
    retryDelayOnTryAgain: 3000,
    slotsRefreshTimeout: 200000000000000,
    clusterRetryStrategy: (times) => Math.min(times * 1000, 10000),
    dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
    scaleReads: 'slave',
    showFriendlyErrorStack: true,
    redisOptions: {
        keyPrefix: config.queue.prefix,
        autoResubscribe: true,
        autoResendUnfulfilledCommands: true
    }
}

const redisClientInstance = new Redis.Cluster([{ host: '', port: ''}], clusterOptions);
```

But trying to access the Redis always results in a `Failed refresh slots cache`. Anyone else dealt with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works for me.

**Redis version**: *5.0.4* on `AWS ElastiCache` Clustered with `TLS` and `AUTH` enabled.

**ioredis version**: *4.16.0*

Code to connect:

```
const redis = new Redis.Cluster(
            [{ "host": <ELASTI_CACHE_CONFIGURATION_ENDPOINT> }], {
                dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
                redisOptions: {
                    tls: true,
                    password: <ELASTI_CACHE_REDIS_AUTH>
                }
            });
```

When you launch `ElastiCache`, you will need to specify one or more `Subnet Group` (generally private Subnets) and the `Security Group`. When you run the above code from any compute (Lambda, EC2 etc.), you need to ensure the following

- `ElastiCache` is reachable from your Compute (Put the compute in a Subnet which can communicate with the Subnet of the `ElastiCache` in the same `VPC`. If the compute and `Elasticache` are on different VPCs, ensure VPC peering enabled between them.)
- Ensure the `Security Group`, `NACL` allows the connection to `ElastiCache` port (`6379` is the default) from your Compute `Subnet`
- Finally ensure the Compute can assume an `IAM Role`(EC2 instance profile, Lambda Role etc) which has appropriate access to `ElastiCache`. In case you are running on an EC2 instance, make sure your code uses the temporary credentials of the Role assigned in the EC2 instance profile.

Comment: What is correct VPC, Subnet, Security Group?

Comment: @VinitKhandelwal updates with more details about correct VPC, Subnet, SG etc. Highly recommend going through the documentation.

Comment: I tried your solution, yet after sometime, it throws error 'ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache'

Comment: Sadly, this still returns [ioredis] Unhandled error event: ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache, for redis engine 6.2.5 and 4.16.0 of ioredis

Comment: Have you tried by using `enableReadyCheck`: true in the client configuration?

Comment: Hi, i found some another option [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis?activeTab=readme#special-note-aws-elasticache-clusters-with-tls). Works for my aws memorydb cluster with enabled TLS.

Comment: I have my redis hosted on aws and I am trying to connect to it from a batch job within the same AWS account and I am getting the same error in the question above. Works fine when trying to connect from local system.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting your client to debug mode

For ioredis you can do it like so:

```
DEBUG=ioredis:* node app.js
```

**There might be an error you're not seeing**

In my case there was `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` printed before the `Failed to refresh slots cache` error was thrown

Comment: This is giving me the error `'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: @Srk95 if you are on Windows the command will be different: 
`set DEBUG=ioredis:* & node app.js`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but with small hack as i am using it in typescript, faced issue while passing null to first argument for callback function which expecting `NodeJS.ErrnoException` and does't want to allow using any type(due to eslint `no-explicit-any` rule).

I used @ts-expect-error directive above dnsLookup

```
    // @ts-expect-error this will ignore error
    dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying any solution here, once verify that you are creating cluster with cluster mode enabled, this thing worked for me!

Here's an attached screenshot.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems the `slotsRefreshTimeout` was the problem. Included the option to increase the timeout and the error is not showing anymore. Here is my connection example:

```
let client = new Cluster([
    { port: 6379, host: <END_POINT> }
],{
    dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
    slotsRefreshTimeout: 2000,
    redisOptions: { tls: true }
});
```