# Connecting to redis using tls (ssl) and auth_token password in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis

I am trying to connect to a redis instance in aws. I can connect to it using something like

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 -a <auth_token> --tls PING
```

However when I try this using node (redis library v4.2.0) doing something like this, it hangs

```
const redis = require("redis");

(async () => {
  const client = redis.createClient( {
    auth_pass:
      "<auth_token>",
    tls: { servername: "localhost", port: 6379 },
  });
  client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Redis Client Error", err);
  });
  client.connect();
  console.log(await client.ping());
})();
```

Portforwarding is setup for redis in aws, which is why localhost is used.
The auth token is the same token I entered to the sparkleformation when redis was configured. both resting and transit encryption has been configured as well.
I have been trying to poke around on google for an answer, however there seem to be a lot of old documentation out there and none of the new ones are clear as to how to get a connection working using tls and an auth token. Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: This is an old question, but you're using the attribute 'tls.servername' in this example, did you try 'tls.host' instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anybody is running into the same issue, I was able to get it working using ioredis instead.

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
(async () => {
  const redisRef = new Redis("rediss://:<auth_token>@localhost:6379");

  console.log(await redisRef.ping());
})();
```

and setting this environment variable when running locally:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across to the same issue with `node-redis` v4 (`redis@4.6.7` in npm) and accepted solution also works there with a little bit of modification:

```
const { createClient} = require('redis');

(async () => {
  const client = createClient({
    url: "redis://:<auth_token>@localhost:6379");
  });

  await client.connect();

  console.log(await client.ping());
})();
```

Here one of the main things to keep in mind is the `protocol` (I mean `redis://` and `rediss://`).

You must keep in mind that `rediss://` protocol enables `tls`, and if your redis host doesn't support tls (like in this case localhost) you will get TimeOut error or it will just hang.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours these settings have worked for me with AWS ElastiCache. Hopefully I save someone some life.

- Using node **redis** standalone
  https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md

```js
    const standalone = createClient({
        password: '<PASSWORD>', // use your password here
        socket: {
            host: 'host.cache-cluster.com',
            port: 6379,
            tls: true
        }
    });
```

- Using node **redis** cluster
  https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/clustering.md

```js
    const cluster = createCluster({
      rootNodes: [{url: 'redis://host.cache-cluster.com:6379'}],
      defaults: {
        password: '<PASSWORD>',
        socket: {
            tls: true
        }
      }
    });
```

- Using node **ioredis** cluster
  Originally found here [ioredis - ClusterAllFailedError: Failed to refresh slots cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350961/ioredis-clusterallfailederror-failed-to-refresh-slots-cache)

```js
    const cluster = new Redis.Cluster(
      [{ host: 'host.cache-cluster.com' }], {
      dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
      redisOptions: {
          tls: true,
          password: '<PASSWORD>'
          }
      });
```